# How to detect shift in image?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy, fft

I try to detect shift in image with fft2. I find a code to do that but I dont really understand why the shift value is incorrect. 
Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import fftpack
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import scipy.signal

def cross_image(im1, im2):
   im1_gray = np.sum(im1.astype('float'), axis=2)
   im2_gray = np.sum(im2.astype('float'), axis=2)
   im1_gray -= np.mean(im1_gray)
   im2_gray -= np.mean(im2_gray)
   image1FFT = np.conjugate( np.fft.fft2(im1_gray) )
   image2FFT = np.conjugate( np.fft.fft2(im2_gray) )
   imageCCor = np.real( np.fft.ifft2( (image1FFT*image2FFT) ) )
   return imageCCor
   # return scipy.signal.fftconvolve(im1_gray, im2_gray[::-1,::-1], mode='same')

def plot_spectrum(im_fft):
    from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm
    # A logarithmic colormap
    plt.imshow(np.abs(im_fft), norm=LogNorm(vmin=5))
    plt.colorbar()

im = mpimg.imread('/home/xavier/0001.jpg')     

plt.figure()
plt.imshow(im, plt.cm.gray)
plt.title('Original image')


xPixelShift = 25
yPixelShift = -7
row, col,channels     = im.shape
relativeSize = np.floor( min( 1-abs(xPixelShift)/col, 1-abs(yPixelShift)/row ) * 10 ) /10

x0 = int( (col - col*relativeSize)/2 )
x1 = col-x0 + 1
y0 = int( (row - row*relativeSize)/2 )
y1 = row-y0 + 1

# not shifted ROI
image1 = im[y0:y1,x0:x1].copy()
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image1, plt.cm.gray)

# shifted ROI
image2 = im[y0+yPixelShift:y1+yPixelShift,x0+xPixelShift:x1+xPixelShift].copy()
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(image2, plt.cm.gray)

imageCCorShift = cross_image(image1,image2)
plt.figure()
plt.imshow(imageCCorShift)

row, col,channels     = image1.shape
yShift, xShift = np.unravel_index( np.argmax(imageCCorShift), (row,col) )

print("shift of image1 in x-direction [pixel]: " + str(xShift))
print("shift of image1 in y-direction [pixel]: " + str(yShift))
```

When I use that commented code, it works:

```
scipy.signal.fftconvolve(im1_gray, im2_gray[::-1,::-1], mode='same')
```

But when I use my code, it does work

```
   image1FFT = np.conjugate( np.fft.fft2(im1_gray) )
   image2FFT = np.conjugate( np.fft.fft2(im2_gray) )
   imageCCor = np.real( np.fft.ifft2( (image1FFT*image2FFT) ) )
   return imageCCor
```

What the scipy function fftconvolve do more than my code?

Comment: So it works in any case? You might have forgotten a "not" for any of the two cases?